# file manager update feature

Tags: ruby, file, monitor, gtk3

I want to create a simple file manager. Users can run lots of file manager same time. If any file was deleted, other file managers (other open windows) should update own window. In this case, How can I supply when any file created, deleted update file manager window.

I use for the file manager gtk3 & Ruby. I can use for file monitor some gems. But their logs are very inefficient for me. Because they say file~ created, deleted. But real reason file editor creates their backup file. In this case I couldn't distinguish file~ is real file~ or it is just temprorary file because of text editor. So How can I solve this? Using file monitor gems or other things?

Answer (score 0):

A file is a file.  It is certainly real, it was created, and it was deleted.  You *know* it's something you're not supposed to pay attention to, because you know that particular file was an editor backup.  You don't know that for your users, so you can't make that assumption.

You could, for example, provide a list of commonly ignored files. Something akin to a `.gitignore` file, and not pay attention to files matching the ignore list.